# Toggle (if exists) nested element

Tags: jquery, click, toggle

HTML:

```
<ul class="parent">
   <li><a href="#">toggler</a>
       <ul class="child">
       ...
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to toggle 'child' UL (if it exists) via 'toggler' link. There might me multiple parent>child elements so I'd like to toggle the relevant child only.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UL is not a child to the anchor, but using `next()` is simple enough:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
     $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Given your link has an id:

```
<a id="Mylink" href="#">
```

The jQuery would be:

```
$("#MyLink").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('.child').toggle();
});
```

You could select directly by element and class instead of ID:

```
$('ul.parent li a')
```

But ID selectors are generally considered to be faster

The toggle function also accepts a parameter if you wish to animate, e.g.

```
    $(this).siblings('.child').toggle('slow');  /or 'medium', or 'fast'
    $(this).siblings('.child').toggle(100); //100 millisecs
```

A variation to this is slideToggle, with the same parameters.

```
    $(this).siblings('.child').slideToggle('slow');
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/toggle

Comment: .child is a sibling of the anchor, not a child.

Comment: Good spot. Some would have constitued that a down-vote. Have corrected accordigly. +1 for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul.parent li a').click(function(event) {

    $(this).next('ul.child').slideToggle(500);
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Have you considered instead of using a link there, a `<button>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a.toggler").click(function(){
   $(this).parent().children('.child').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.parent a').click(function () {
  $('.child', this.parentNode).toggle();
});
```